# How to add term programmatically in Paragraph field?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, paragraphs

I have a paragraph with a taxonomy reference (autocomplete) field and I want to populate it when I create programmatically a pararagraph item.
I checked the option "Create referenced entities if they do not already exist" in this field.

I use this code, but I don't know how to find more informations to do that without Term::create (if it's possible) :

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;

        foreach ($field_value as $creator_type => $creator_name) {

            $paragraph = Paragraph::create(['type' => '_zotero_ref_creators']);
            //text field
            $paragraph->set('field_nom_prenom_createur', $creator_name);
            //taxo reference field
            $paragraph->set('field_type_createurs', $creator_type);

            //$paragraph->isNew();
            $paragraph->save();

            $paragraphn_field_value = array(
              'target_id' => $paragraph->id(),
              'target_revision_id' => $paragraph->getRevisionId(),
            );

            $node_reference->set('field_liste_contrib', $paragraphn_field_value);
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First load the node already created.
Second, create a paragraph like you did but for taxonomy term add "target_id" and for value choose a term id. 
Set the paragraph value to your field of type paragraph from node. Also you need to save the node.

```
    $node = Node::load($nid);    
     $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
            'type' => 'gallery_image',
            'field_type_createurs' => ['target_id' => $value],
          ]);
          $paragraph->save();

          $current[] = [
            'target_id' => $paragraph->id(),
            'target_revision_id' =>$paragraph->getRevisionId(),
          ];

   $node->set('your_field', $current);
   $node->save();
```

Varible $value is a term id.

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It took awhile for this to sink in. Thinking of it as creating a paragraph entity on the node helped me with `Paragraph::create`. A first I was thinking of `Paragraph::create` as creating the paragraph type, which, of course, I had already created.

Here's some more example code that is mostly a repeat of @OPTASY's code. All the data is sanitized and, hopefully, the keys give a clear idea which fields are being referenced and when.

```
$node = Node::load($nid);

$current = [];
  $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
    'type' => 'my_paragraph_type',
    'field_from_my_paragraph_type' => ['target_id' => 1]
  ]);
  $paragraph->save();

$current[] = [
    'target_id' => $paragraph->id(),
    'target_revision_id' => $paragraph->getRevisionId(),
  ];

$node->set('field_from_my_content_type', $current);
$node->save();
```